# Validación en backend/frontend y/o usuarios concurrentes

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, express-session, backend, redis

Tengo entendido que las validaciones se tienen que hacer a nivel de backend por seguridad, pero lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente, validar a nivel de frontend con angular, y así hacer que el servidor trabaje menos, por decir, pero si lo hago en el frontend el usuario podría modificar el script y todo lo que haga, para poder enviar lo que se le antoje, entonces como podría hacer una función, en el backend que me diga que el usuario esta validado, así éste ya no tiene que hacer otra validación de nuevo. ¿Alguna idea?.

Con respecto a mi 2° pregunta, estoy usando nodejs para correr un servidor con sesiones almacenadas en redis con express session, pero esta al hacer pruebas con loadtest npm, con 20 usuarios concurrentes me empieza a salir errores en que req.session no se encuentra, ¿Cómo podría mejorar el rendimiento de las sesiones?

Comment: Por seguridad debes de hacer validaciones en ambos lados.

Comment: Deberías de crear otra pregunta en stackoverflow sobre tu segunda duda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Las validaciones en el back-end hay que hacerlas siempre**. La ventaja de trabajar en nodejs es que algunas rutinas de validación se pueden programar una sola vez y son las mismas las que corren en el backend y en el frontend (por ejemplo que el mail sea válido y de ciertos dominios, la función Javascript validamail que programes para esto se puede usar en ambos lugares).

*Respecto al ahorro*:

1. Hay ahorro de procesamiento en el back-end porque (salvo que sea un atacante) si algo ya se comprobó inválido en el front-end no se va a enviar al back-end (¿por qué lo validamos en el front-end entonces? porque los ataques sí existen).
2. Hay ahorro de programación (en las funciones que se pueden usar en ambos sitios)